# Concat multi columns, different date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have an dataframe, with multi columns date and value. I would like concat the dataframe with one column date and every columns value. I try this code but it's not best, because it's static and I can't use the name columns in my code.

```
fichier_maitreVL = "P:/GESTION_RPSE/GES - Gestion Epargne Salariale//01_OUTILS_ET_PROCESS/Validation 
VL/S2G/Archivage/Pending-Files CSV/Histo.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(fichier_maitreVL)
del df['Unnamed: 0']
df_Historique = df

new_df = pd.concat([df[['Date_L1281', 'L1281']].rename(columns={'Date_L1281': 'date'}), 
df[['Date_L1319', 'L1319']].rename(columns={'Date_L1319': 'date'}), df[['Date_J3S', 
'J3S']].rename(columns={'Date_J3S': 'date'}),df[['Date_L1315', 'L1315']].rename(columns= 
{'Date_L1315': 'date'}),df[['Date_E200122', 'E200122']].rename(columns={'Date_E200122': 
'date'}),df[['Date_L1266', 'L1266']].rename(columns={'Date_L1266': 'date'}),df[['Date_L1270', 
'L1270']].rename(columns={'Date_L1270': 'date'}),df[['Date_L1315', 'L1315']].rename(columns= 
{'Date_L1315': 'date'}),df[['Date_L1318', 'L1318']].rename(columns={'Date_L1318': 
'date'}),df[['Date_L22145S', 'L22145S']].rename(columns={'Date_L22145S': 'date'}),df[['Date_L1321S', 
'L1321S']].rename(columns={'Date_L1321S': 'date'}),df[['Date_PF52245', 'PF52245']].rename(columns= 
{'Date_PF52245': 'date'})],sort=True)
```

[My intpout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xwPl.png)

I would like the value inpout, all columns L1281, L1319 ect.. and juste one columns for all Date.

Comment: please provide copyable input data and required output

Comment: Yes, no problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try sth like this:

```
df.set_index('Date_L1281', inplace=True)
df.drop(list(df.filter(regex = 'Date')), axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Yes, but i suppose to have the same date in my columns.. And this is not the case

Answer (score 0):

[Inpout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJFHA.png)
And for my Output, i just want the all columns value and just one columns date with the all date in.

Answer (score 0):

Date_J3S = ['2018-12-24', '2018-12-27', '2018-12-28', '2018-12-31', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-
03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-08', '2019-01-09', '2019-01-10', '2019
-01-11', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-15', '2019-01-16', '2019-01-17', '2019-01-18', '
2019-01-21', '2019-01-22', '2019-01-23', '2019-01-24', '2019-01-25', '2019-01-28
', '2019-01-29', '2019-01-30', '2019-01-31', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-04', '2019-0
2-05', '2019-02-06', '2019-02-07', '2019-02-08', '2019-02-11', '2019-02-12', '20
19-02-13', '2019-02-14', '2019-02-15', '2019-02-18', '2019-02-19', '2019-02-20',
 '2019-02-21', '2019-02-22', '2019-02-25', '2019-02-26', '2019-02-27', '2019-02-
28', '2019-03-01', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-05', '2019-03-06', '2019-03-07', '2019
-03-08', '2019-03-11', '2019-03-12', '2019-03-13', '2019-03-14', '2019-03-15', '
2019-03-18', '2019-03-19', '2019-03-20', '2019-03-21', '2019-03-22', '2019-03-25
', '2019-03-26', '2019-03-27', '2019-03-28', '2019-03-29', '2019-04-01', '2019-0
4-02', '2019-04-03', '2019-04-04', '2019-04-05', '2019-04-08', '2019-04-09', '20
19-04-10', '2019-04-11', '2019-04-12', '2019-04-15', '2019-04-16', '2019-04-17',
 '2019-04-18', '2019-04-23', '2019-04-24', '2019-04-25', '2019-04-26', '2019-04-
29', '2019-04-30', '2019-05-02', '2019-05-03', '2019-05-06', '2019-05-07', '2019
-05-08', '2019-05-09', '2019-05-10', '2019-05-13', '2019-05-14', '2019-05-15', '
2019-05-16', '2019-05-17', '2019-05-20', '2019-05-21', '2019-05-22', '2019-05-23
', '2019-05-24', '2019-05-27', '2019-05-28', '2019-05-29', '2019-05-30', '2019-0
5-31', '2019-06-03', '2019-06-04', '2019-06-05', '2019-06-06', '2019-06-07', '20
19-06-10', '2019-06-11', '2019-06-12', '2019-06-13', '2019-06-14', '2019-06-17',
 '2019-06-18', '2019-06-19', '2019-06-20', '2019-06-21', '2019-06-24', '2019-06-
25', '2019-06-26', '2019-06-27', '2019-06-28', '2019-07-01', '2019-07-02', '2019
-07-03', '2019-07-04', '2019-07-05', '2019-07-08', '2019-07-09', '2019-07-10', '
2019-07-11', '2019-07-12', '2019-07-15', '2019-07-16', '2019-07-17', '2019-07-18
', '2019-07-19', '2019-07-22', '2019-07-23', '2019-07-24', '2019-07-25', '2019-0
7-26', '2019-07-29', '2019-07-30', '2019-07-31', '2019-08-01', '2019-08-02', '20
19-08-05', '2019-08-06', '2019-08-07', '2019-08-08', '2019-08-09', '2019-08-12',
 '2019-08-13', '2019-08-14', '2019-08-15', '2019-08-16', '2019-08-19', '2019-08-
20', '2019-08-21', '2019-08-22', '2019-08-23', '2019-08-26', '2019-08-27', '2019
-08-28', '2019-08-29', '2019-08-30', '2019-09-02', '2019-09-03', '2019-09-04', '
2019-09-05', '2019-09-06', '2019-09-09', '2019-09-10', '2019-09-11', '2019-09-12
', '2019-09-13', '2019-09-16', '2019-09-17', '2019-09-18', '2019-09-19', '2019-0
9-20', '2019-09-23', '2019-09-24', '2019-09-25', '2019-09-26', '2019-09-27', '20
19-09-30', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-02', '2019-10-03', '2019-10-04', '2019-10-07',
 '2019-10-08', '2019-10-09', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-11', '2019-10-14', '2019-10-
15', '2019-10-16', '2019-10-17', '2019-10-18', '2019-10-21', '2019-10-22', '2019
-10-23', '2019-10-24', '2019-10-25', '2019-10-28', '2019-10-29', '2019-10-30', '
2019-10-31', '2019-11-01', '2019-11-04', '2019-11-05', '2019-11-06', '2019-11-07
', '2019-11-08', '2019-11-11', '2019-11-12', '2019-11-13', '2019-11-14', '2019-1
1-15', '2019-11-18', '2019-11-19', '2019-11-20', '2019-11-21', '2019-11-22', '20
19-11-25', '2019-11-26', '2019-11-27', '2019-11-28', '2019-11-29', '2019-12-02',
 '2019-12-03', '2019-12-04', '2019-12-05', '2019-12-06', '2019-12-09', '2019-12-
10', '2019-12-11', '2019-12-12', '2019-12-13']

Value_J3S = [1005.1385, 1005.1106, 1005.1018, 1005.0737, 1005.0549, 1005.0449, 1005.0351, 10
05.0082, 1004.9979, 1004.988, 1004.9779, 1004.9699, 1004.9396, 1004.93, 1004.920
7, 1004.9107, 1004.9013, 1004.8697, 1004.8603, 1004.8509, 1004.8414, 1004.8322, 
1004.8004, 1004.7909, 1004.7816, 1004.7724, 1004.7624, 1004.7297, 1004.7203, 100
4.7102, 1004.7008, 1004.6912, 1004.6591, 1004.6495, 1004.6397, 1004.6295, 1004.6
196, 1004.5912, 1004.5808, 1004.5713, 1004.5618, 1004.5521, 1004.5246, 1004.5161
, 1004.5060000000001, 1004.4968, 1004.4877, 1004.46, 1004.4505, 1004.4412, 1004.
432, 1004.4228, 1004.3932, 1004.3838, 1004.3746, 1004.3648, 1004.3580000000001, 
1004.3316, 1004.3214, 1004.3141, 1004.3047, 1004.2947, 1004.2660000000001, 1004.
2566, 1004.2477, 1004.2387, 1004.23, 1004.2037, 1004.1946, 1004.1905, 1004.1817,
 1004.1732, 1004.1472, 1004.1375, 1004.1284, 1004.1184, 1004.1089999999999, 1004
.082, 1004.0727, 1004.0629, 1004.0544, 1004.0079, 1003.9991, 1003.9897, 1003.980
3, 1003.9533, 1003.9446, 1003.9266, 1003.9178, 1003.8897, 1003.8805, 1003.872, 1
003.8629, 1003.8539999999999, 1003.826, 1003.817, 1003.8077, 1003.7976, 1003.788
9, 1003.7628, 1003.7525, 1003.7425, 1003.7323, 1003.7224, 1003.6974, 1003.6884, 
1003.6787, 1003.6701, 1003.6607, 1003.6359, 1003.6265, 1003.6178, 1003.6086, 100
3.5989, 1003.5824, 1003.5716, 1003.5625, 1003.5533, 1003.5436, 1003.5158, 1003.5
059, 1003.4968, 1003.4901, 1003.4808, 1003.4635, 1003.4542, 1003.4452, 1003.436,
 1003.4272, 1003.4094, 1003.3995, 1003.3905, 1003.3813, 1003.3716, 1003.3483, 10
03.3382, 1003.3282, 1003.3183, 1003.3084, 1003.2904, 1003.2805, 1003.2712, 1003.
2618, 1003.2527, 1003.2331, 1003.2263, 1003.2175, 1003.2081, 1003.1986, 1003.178
3, 1003.1688, 1003.1597, 1003.1502, 1003.1409, 1003.1219, 1003.1127, 1003.1033, 
1003.0935, 1003.084, 1003.0667, 1003.0578, 1003.0484, 1003.0397, 1003.0297, 1003
.0168, 1003.0075, 1002.9978, 1002.9886, 1002.9805, 1002.9654, 1002.9562, 1002.94
7, 1002.9378, 1002.9286, 1002.9116, 1002.9031, 1002.8932, 1002.8839999999999, 10
02.8741, 1002.8558, 1002.8459, 1002.8359, 1002.8272, 1002.8179, 1002.7972, 1002.
7872, 1002.7771, 1002.7659, 1002.7563, 1002.7268, 1002.7154, 1002.7047, 1002.693
5, 1002.6819, 1002.6519, 1002.6411, 1002.63, 1002.6189, 1002.6077, 1002.5862, 10
02.5741, 1002.5629, 1002.5513, 1002.5394, 1002.5036, 1002.4922, 1002.4812, 1002.
4702, 1002.4586, 1002.4288, 1002.4172, 1002.4057, 1002.3945, 1002.3836, 1002.362
4, 1002.3506, 1002.3393, 1002.3277, 1002.3172, 1002.2844, 1002.2751, 1002.2647, 
1002.2539999999999, 1002.2432, 1002.2124, 1002.2005, 1002.1894, 1002.1789, 1002.
1683, 1002.1388, 1002.1277, 1002.1168, 1002.1063, 1002.0949, 1002.0625, 1002.051
2, 1002.0402, 1002.0284, 1002.0169, 1001.9833, 1001.9713, 1001.9597, 1001.9487, 
1001.9376, 1001.9034, 1001.8919999999999, 1001.8811, 1001.87, 1001.8599]

Date_L1321S = ['2018-12-24', '2018-12-27', '2018-12-28', '2018-12-31', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-
03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-08', '2019-01-09', '2019-01-10', '2019
-01-11', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-15', '2019-01-16', '2019-01-17', '2019-01-18', '
2019-01-21', '2019-01-22', '2019-01-23', '2019-01-24', '2019-01-25', '2019-01-28
', '2019-01-29', '2019-01-30', '2019-01-31', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-04', '2019-0
2-05', '2019-02-06', '2019-02-07', '2019-02-08', '2019-02-11', '2019-02-12', '20
19-02-13', '2019-02-14', '2019-02-15', '2019-02-18', '2019-02-19', '2019-02-20',
 '2019-02-21', '2019-02-22', '2019-02-25', '2019-02-26', '2019-02-27', '2019-02-
28', '2019-03-01', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-05', '2019-03-06', '2019-03-07', '2019
-03-08', '2019-03-11', '2019-03-12', '2019-03-13', '2019-03-14', '2019-03-15', '
2019-03-18', '2019-03-19', '2019-03-20', '2019-03-21', '2019-03-22', '2019-03-25
', '2019-03-26', '2019-03-27', '2019-03-28', '2019-03-29', '2019-04-01', '2019-0
4-02', '2019-04-03', '2019-04-04', '2019-04-05', '2019-04-08', '2019-04-09', '20
19-04-10', '2019-04-11', '2019-04-12', '2019-04-15', '2019-04-16', '2019-04-17',
 '2019-04-18', '2019-04-23', '2019-04-24', '2019-04-25', '2019-04-26', '2019-04-
29', '2019-04-30', '2019-05-02', '2019-05-03', '2019-05-06', '2019-05-07', '2019
-05-09', '2019-05-10', '2019-05-13', '2019-05-14', '2019-05-15', '2019-05-16', '
2019-05-17', '2019-05-20', '2019-05-21', '2019-05-22', '2019-05-23', '2019-05-24
', '2019-05-27', '2019-05-28', '2019-05-29', '2019-05-31', '2019-06-03', '2019-0
6-04', '2019-06-05', '2019-06-06', '2019-06-07', '2019-06-11', '2019-06-12', '20
19-06-13', '2019-06-14', '2019-06-17', '2019-06-18', '2019-06-19', '2019-06-20',
 '2019-06-21', '2019-06-24', '2019-06-25', '2019-06-26', '2019-06-27', '2019-06-
28', '2019-07-01', '2019-07-02', '2019-07-03', '2019-07-04', '2019-07-05', '2019
-07-08', '2019-07-09', '2019-07-10', '2019-07-11', '2019-07-12', '2019-07-15', '
2019-07-16', '2019-07-17', '2019-07-18', '2019-07-19', '2019-07-22', '2019-07-23
', '2019-07-24', '2019-07-25', '2019-07-26', '2019-07-29', '2019-07-30', '2019-0
7-31', '2019-08-01', '2019-08-02', '2019-08-05', '2019-08-06', '2019-08-07', '20
19-08-08', '2019-08-09', '2019-08-12', '2019-08-13', '2019-08-14', '2019-08-16',
 '2019-08-19', '2019-08-20', '2019-08-21', '2019-08-22', '2019-08-23', '2019-08-
26', '2019-08-27', '2019-08-28', '2019-08-29', '2019-08-30', '2019-09-02', '2019
-09-03', '2019-09-04', '2019-09-05', '2019-09-06', '2019-09-09', '2019-09-10', '
2019-09-11', '2019-09-12', '2019-09-13', '2019-09-16', '2019-09-17', '2019-09-18
', '2019-09-19', '2019-09-20', '2019-09-23', '2019-09-24', '2019-09-25', '2019-0
9-26', '2019-09-27', '2019-09-30', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-02', '2019-10-03', '20
19-10-04', '2019-10-07', '2019-10-08', '2019-10-09', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-11',
 '2019-10-14', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-16', '2019-10-17', '2019-10-18', '2019-10-
21', '2019-10-22', '2019-10-23', '2019-10-24', '2019-10-25', '2019-10-28', '2019
-10-29', '2019-10-30', '2019-10-31', '2019-11-04', '2019-11-05', '2019-11-06', '
2019-11-07', '2019-11-08', '2019-11-12', '2019-11-13', '2019-11-14', '2019-11-15
', '2019-11-18', '2019-11-19', '2019-11-20', '2019-11-21', '2019-11-22', '2019-1
1-25', '2019-11-26', '2019-11-27', '2019-11-28', '2019-11-29', '2019-12-02', '20
19-12-03', '2019-12-04', '2019-12-05', '2019-12-06', '2019-12-09', '2019-12-10',
 '2019-12-11', '2019-12-12', '2019-12-13']

Value_L1321S = [96.83, 96.81, 96.85, 96.87, 97.06, 96.97, 96.77, 96.61, 96.35, 96.29, 96.65, 96
.71, 96.86, 97.04, 97.0, 97.1, 97.06, 97.11, 97.09, 97.2, 97.42, 97.61, 97.6, 97
.58, 97.55, 97.76, 97.6, 97.57, 97.47, 97.4, 97.28, 97.4, 97.35, 97.42, 97.49, 9
7.53, 97.46, 97.69, 97.65, 97.68, 97.66, 97.6, 97.73, 97.84, 97.77, 97.51, 97.45
, 97.4, 97.57, 97.7, 97.83, 98.31, 98.29, 98.17, 98.18, 98.27, 98.25, 98.44, 98.
49, 98.34, 98.58, 98.91, 98.95, 98.93, 99.16, 99.16, 99.15, 98.88, 98.84, 98.76,
 98.74, 98.78, 98.94, 98.99, 99.13, 99.24, 99.17, 98.86, 98.65, 98.59, 98.86, 98
.66, 98.75, 98.86, 98.9, 99.13, 98.89, 99.12, 99.05, 99.15, 99.27, 99.22, 99.09,
 99.08, 99.11, 99.25, 99.5, 99.62, 99.46, 99.4, 99.42, 99.5, 99.68, 99.8, 99.71,
 99.97, 100.03, 100.46, 100.52, 100.62, 100.9, 101.09, 101.15, 101.08, 101.06, 1
01.37, 101.4, 101.88, 101.97, 102.32, 102.08, 102.19, 102.12, 102.16, 102.13, 10
2.32, 102.41, 102.85, 103.27, 103.59, 103.56, 103.17, 102.99, 102.62, 102.87, 10
2.15, 102.33, 102.9, 102.92, 103.11, 103.19, 103.18, 103.07, 103.53, 103.73, 103
.43, 103.7, 103.55, 103.76, 103.82, 104.34, 104.82, 104.8, 105.32, 105.15, 104.6
2, 104.59, 104.91, 105.16, 106.38, 105.58, 105.63, 105.66, 105.82, 105.38, 105.6
3, 105.92, 106.48, 106.75, 106.57, 106.55, 106.86, 106.53, 106.18, 105.66, 105.7
2, 105.43, 105.08, 105.55, 105.09, 105.01, 105.08, 105.14, 105.21, 105.46, 106.0
5, 106.06, 106.44, 106.2, 106.19, 105.95, 105.61, 105.77, 105.96, 106.2, 106.15,
 105.94, 105.93, 105.7, 105.22, 105.18, 105.28, 105.13, 104.75, 104.83, 104.42, 
104.67, 105.0, 104.79, 104.81, 104.33, 104.45, 104.47, 104.93, 104.4, 104.13, 10
4.11, 104.23, 103.55, 103.1, 103.58, 103.7, 103.6, 103.64, 103.81, 104.02, 103.8
, 103.81, 103.85, 103.96, 104.09, 103.94, 103.84, 103.2, 103.07, 103.57, 103.38,
 103.18, 103.35, 103.27, 103.61, 103.7, 103.3]